# "Could not attach to pid: " when running app on device

Tags: xcode, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm new to watchOS development and I want to run a simple hello world app on my device.

The app consists of just a label and a button. When I try to run the app I get the following error:

> Could not attach to pid: xxxx

[image: watch]

I'm on watchOS 2.1., iOS9.3 and Xcode 7.3.1.

How do I fix that?

Comment: try to restart your watch.

Comment: you should post any `awakeWithContext()` or `willActivate()` code to show what your interface controller might be trying to do when it loads.

Comment: I tried to restart but no use. @kai

Comment: I solved issue. It's a provision issue. I changed the right provision, everything is ok now. Thanks all.

Comment: Please post your answer, instead of answering in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it was a provision issue. Choosing the right provisioning profile fixed it. Everything is OK now.